# Could not decode string. (line 2, file "Code", project "PROJECT NAME")

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I've been trying to create an HTML form that uploads a file into google drive.

here is the code I used in google  app scripts:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.data);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameters.mimetype, e.parameters.filename);
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.")
}
```

and here is how my HTML form looks like :

```
<form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx48QW8vH7C0cse4W60VJIXba4MVkUxiuUTaJPZ1_MWwUrODMmp/exec" id="form" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control"><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"><Br>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file" class="form-control">
    <br><Br>
    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
    $('#uploadfile').on("change", function () {
        var file = this.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.fileName = file.name
        fr.onload = function (e) {
            e.target.result
            html = '<input type="hidden" name="data" value="' + e.target.result.replace(/^.*,/, '') + '" >';
            html += '<input type="hidden" name="mimetype" value="' + e.target.result.match(/^.*(?=;)/)[0] + '" >';
            html += '<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="' + e.target.fileName + '" >';
            $("#data").empty().append(html);
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
</script>
```

the URL used `https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx48QW8vH7C0cse4W60VJIXba4MVkUxiuUTaJPZ1_MWwUrODMmp/exec` is the URL I got after deploying the script as a web app.

Now when I try to upload a .txt file it gives me the error `Could not decode the string. (line 2, file "Code", project "PROJET NAME")`

**UPDATE:**

Based on @TheMaster Comment, I found out that I didn't need the decoding part .. so I changed the google script to be like :

```
function doPost(e) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(e.parameters.data, e.parameters.mimetype, e.parameters.filename);
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.")
}
```

But it gave me the error `Invalid argument (line 3, file "Code", project "PROJECT NAME")`

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, you are right, I don't need the decoding part. I changed it but I got another error, check the edit

Comment: Use stackdriver logging  `console.log()` to log `e` and parameters. Check whether any of them  are undefined

Comment: Some how mimetype and filename are undefined !!

Comment: If your script was created by copying other script, can you provide the information of original script? Because although your script uses jquery, it seems that it is not loaded. For example, how about putting ``<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>`` in your script and try again. At that time, please use the first script of Google Apps Script. By the way, I think that in your script, the inputted name and emails are not sent to GAS side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your welcome to this one:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script>

  function fileUploadJs(frmData) 
  {
    document.getElementById('status').style.display ='inline';
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
      .processForm(frmData)
  };
  function updateOutput(info) 
  {
    var br='<br />';
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('status');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = br + 'File Upload Successful.' + br + 'File Name: ' + info.name + br + 'Content Type: ' + info.type;
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="main-heading">Main Heading</h1>
    <div id="formDiv">
      <form id="myForm">
        <input name="fileToLoad" type="file" /><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="fileUploadJs(this.parentNode)" />
      </form>
    </div>
  <div id="status" style="display: none">
  <!-- div will be filled with innerHTML after form submission. -->
  Uploading. Please wait...
  </div>  
  <div id="controls">
      <input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

GS:

```
function processForm(theForm) {
  var fileBlob = theForm.fileToLoad;
  Logger.log("fileBlob Name: " + fileBlob.getName())
  Logger.log("fileBlob type: " + fileBlob.getContentType())
  Logger.log('fileBlob: ' + fileBlob);
  var fileInfo={'name':fileBlob.getName(),'type':fileBlob.getContentType(), 'size':fileBlob.getBytes()};

  var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderId');//put in fetched files
  fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob);
  return fileInfo;
}
```

I just use it as a dialog so you'll have to add the doGet();